# How to animate when you use classList.remove or classList.Add

Tags: javascript, css

the following code is this.

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const showBox = function () {
  box.classList.remove('hidden');
}

const closeBox = function () {
  box.classList.add('hidden')
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox );
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  position: absolute;
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);

    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

The problem is the animation don't work on classList.remove. I want to make same animation , or reverse or another.

You can find the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n8o9u6d/) here.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added another `class` to show and hide the `box` with the existing animation but played in reverse. I added an `eventListener` for `animationend` to remove the necessary classes.

Here's your solution:

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const showBox = function() {
  box.classList.add('will-show');
  box.classList.remove('hidden');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    box.classList.remove('will-show');
    box.classList.add('shown');
    console.log(box.classList.value);
  }, {once: true});
}

const closeBox = function() {
  box.classList.add('will-hide');
  //shown class was removed here
  box.classList.remove('shown');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    box.classList.remove('will-hide');
    box.classList.add('hidden');

    //supposed to be box hidden only
    console.log(box.classList.value);
  }, {once: true});
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox);
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.will-show {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.will-hide {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may add one line to each function like below.

```js
const showBox = function () {
  box.classList.remove('hidden');
   box.classList.add('box')
}

const closeBox = function () {
  box.classList.add('hidden')
    box.classList.remove('box')
}
```

Comment: Could you check this link ? https://jsfiddle.net/8a6u0x3b/

Comment: i checked, same result. i'm using chrome btw. I don't think the problem is chrome.

Comment: It should be something else specific cause I checked and it works in Chrome, Firefox, and Brave.

Comment: By the way you may try adding "opacity: 1;" to box tuple in CSS.

Comment: I tried to clear all browser cookies and history and everything. I have same problem. And opacity give me the same result. I tried with another browsers, like Edge, firefox, opera. Don't work.

Comment: This will not do. removing the class box will remove all the css properties that made it a box in the first place.

Comment: Dear Marick actually JSfiddle you actually provide even works in my case. Prosy you are right. Adding an extra class will solve that problem if it happens. like "box box2" or "box box-css box-handle" but that is not the problem here.